# Error in for loop in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an error in a datatable , that I want to present it in the aspx code. (%>)

it throw me an exception :

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

this is the code :

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < DTview.Rows.Count; i++)%>
     <% {%>
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["blog_total_views"].ToString(); %></tr>
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["first_name"].ToString(); %></tr>
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["is_affiliate"].ToString(); %></tr>
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["rating"].ToString(); %></tr>
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["price"].ToString(); %></tr> 
        <tr><%=DTview.Rows[i]["current_city"].ToString(); %></tr>
      <%}%>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you also need a `<td>` in there?

Comment: I don't think the semicolon is allowed at the end of the statement.

Comment: And where are the specific error details referenced in your error message? What do they say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%for (int i = 0; i < DTview.Rows.Count; i++)%>
 <% {%>
    <tr>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["blog_total_views"] %></td>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["first_name"] %></td>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["is_affiliate"] %></td>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["rating"] %></td>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["price"] %></td>
        <td><%=DTview.Rows[i]["current_city"] %></td>
     </tr>
  <%}%>
```

You have to drop semi-colons(;) when using <%=%>, coz it will writer the output of the variable directly, also you will get a Null Exception using .ToString() when the field value is null.

Comment: I guess you (or the OP) should leave out all but the first `<tr>` and all but the last `</tr>`.

Comment: @hans, thanks i think for every iteration there should only 1 <tr> created

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
<% foreach (DataRowView row in DTview)
{ %>
   <tr><td><%= row["blog_total_views"].ToString() %></td></tr>
   // Rest of the rows
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not good, to say the least.

Ideal way to display data from DataTable as HTML table is using the [GridView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) - this give you most flexibility and control over the data.

If you're not eager to spend time learning how to use the above it's fine, the "second best" approach for what you need is Repeater control so I'll give the required code for this.

First, have such `.aspx` markup:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptMyView" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><table><tbody></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "blog_total_views")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "first_name")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "is_affiliate")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rating")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "price")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "current_city")%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></tbody></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in the code behind: (e.g. Page_Load method)

```
rptMyView.DataSource = DTview;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```